# MySQL Server has gone away with mysqli_connect to another LAMP Stack / TURNKEY Linux

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql, linux

I am trying to connect to another `VM (192.168.16.27)` from `192.168.16.28` to get Data out of the MariaDB Database (joomla).
So my Code is:

`$link = mysqli_connect("192.168.16.27", "user", "userpassword", "joomladb");`

It works if I insert localhost instead of the IP adress and host it from the same server. I as well changed the bind_adress from both servers from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` and expanded the `max_allowed_packet` to `512M`.

I´m just trying to SELECT a single ID from one table of the joomladb.

But I only get the error message - MySQL Server has gone away - and a blank white sheet

So my question is: Does anyone have another idea what could go wrong in here?
(Someone from Stack Overflow lead me to this site.)
Thanks for any advice!

EDIT:

I´ve tried to add the Port as well:

`$link = mysqli_connect("192.168.16.27:3306", "user", "userpassword", "joomladb");`

`$link = mysqli_connect("192.168.16.27:3307", "user", "userpassword", "joomladb");`

nothing changed.

EDITEDIT:

more code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("192.168.16.27", "user", "userpassword", "joomladb");
$sql_news = "SELECT introtext FROM jos_content WHERE id = '543'";
$result_query = mysqli_query($link, $sql_news);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result_query)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_query)) 
  {
     $news = $row["introtext"];
  }
}
else 
{
  echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for your question. Please take our [tour] to familiarise yourself with this Stack Exchange community.